# How can I strip figures and table during a pandoc LaTeX to Word conversion?

Tags: latex, pandoc, figure

I am trying to use pandoc to convert a thesis from latex to docx. In general, this works well with the following command:

```
pandoc input.tex -f latex -t docx -s -o output.docx --bibliography references.bib --csl=mystyle.csl
```

However, I have an additional requirement that I am unable to fulfill. I want the output to be stripped from any figures and tables that are included in the source files. Reading the pandoc documentation and related stackoverflow question has not helped me so far.

Do you have suggestions on what could do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a poster use-case for [pandoc filters](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html).  The following Lua filter will delete all tables and images:

```lua
function Image () return {} end
function Table () return {} end
```

Save it to a file, say `remove-tables-images.lua`, and pass the file to pandoc via the `--lua-filter` parameter:

```
pandoc input.tex -s -o output.docx \
    --bibliography references.bib --csl=mystyle.csl \
    --lua-filter remove-tables-images.lua
```

Comment: For some reason, regular tables get stripped but the ones in the longtable environment do not. However, apart from that your solution is working perfectly, thanks!